# I was to have left

Tags: construction

In the following sentence

> I was to **have left on** Thursday. But on Thursday I had a terrible cold, so I decided to wait till Saturday.

I think **was to have left by Thursday** should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence is correct, and it says that the person had to leave **on Thursday**, but couldn't do so because he/she had a cold **on Thursday**.

If you use **'by Thursday'**, it means that he/she could have left on any day prior to Thursday, i.e., on Wednesday or Tuesday etc.

Comment: Is it correct to say - You have to have left today

Comment: No, it's incorrect. 'You had to leave today' or 'You have to leave today' are correct.

Comment: Can I say I am to have left today?

Comment: No, you can say 'I am to leave today' (Present) or 'I had to leave today' (Past) or 'I had to have left today' (Past perfect)